# How to retrieve an array of a class' members from an array of that class?

Tags: c#, arrays

Yeah, poorly worded question, but I really wasn't sure how to phrase it.  :)

Let's say I have a simple class that looks like this:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

and I have an `List<>` of them.  Well, I'd like to be able to get a List of all `Name`s, just like `Dictionary<T,U>` lets me do something like `Dictionary.Keys.ToArray()` and `Dictionary.Values.ToArray()`.  Currently, I'm doing the obvious thing, which is to loop over the array of `Contact`s and create my own Array.  I could be naive, but I just thought there might be a `Dictionary`ish way to get at it in one line of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the list is named `contacts`, here is a linq query that should give you an array of names:

```
var names = (from c in contacts select c.Name).ToArray();
```

Note: it first creates an `IEnumerable<string>` then converts it to an array.

Comment: It should return a IEnumerable<String> first, not List<string>

Comment: @Dave: My approach to learning a technology is to learn one thing at a time and keep adding them to my toolbox.  Once I hit a certain threshold, only then do I jump in head first.  Then I have enough context for new concepts to stick.

Comment: @Dave - look here for a good learning resource for linq: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You could use LINQ:

```
Contact[] contacts = GetContacts();
string[] names = contacts.Select(c => c.Name).ToArray();
```